# How to mock a declared private field?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

How would I go about mocking Person?

```
class Test {
    private Person person;
    ...
    public void testMethod() {
        person.someMethod();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to mock `Person`, using annotations and `mockito`:

```
public class UnitTest {

    @Mock
    private Person person;

    @InjectMocks
    private Test test = new Test();

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        test.testMethod();
    }
}
```